# What permissions are required to use System.Speech.Synthesis?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-to-text, speechsynthesizer

I'm using [System.Speech.Synthesis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) from .NET 4.5.1 to generate a WAV file from a string in a Service run by a "specific user" (created by products setup) with no rights but running services and R/W access the folder containing the generated WAV file.

On a fresh win7sp1 x64 with all upgrades, calling methods like [System.Speech.Synthesis.SelectVoice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586901(v=vs.110).aspx) or [System.Speech.Synthesis.Speak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586901(v=vs.110).aspx) fails with `InvalidOperationException` and message "No voice installed on the system or none available with the current security setting".

The only available voice in the system is the default one `Microsoft Anna - English (United States)`.

If I run the service as `LocalSystem` or `Administrator` it works well.

If I add the "specific user" to the `Administrators` group it works too, but not if I add it in any other "well known group".

But running the service with the "specific user" is mandatory (for other uses) and add it to the `Administrators` group is excluded for security reasons.

Of course MSDN is very elusive about this and don't even mention the exception...

Googling around for a while I was surprised by the very few informations about it. In fact I found only one relevant clue in a Stackoverflow question about ASP.NET suggesting there are some minimal user rights to use this library :
[Creating a ASP.NET application converting text to speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech)

> By default, ASP.Net applications don't run with sufficient permissions to access Speech Synthesis

I could also find some questions that are related to the same problem, but with no acceptable answers:

[System.Speech throws "No voice installed on the system or none available with the current security setting" exception in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697668/system-speech-throws-no-voice-installed-on-the-system-or-none-available-with-th)

[No voice installed on the system or none available with the current security setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021200/no-voice-installed-on-the-system-or-none-available-with-the-current-security-set)

[C# SpeechSynthesizer - "No voice installed on the system"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704620/c-sharp-speechsynthesizer-no-voice-installed-on-the-system)

**So do anyone know what permissions are required to use `System.Speech.Synthesis` ?**